# angular named router-outlet doesn't display component

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a `component` inside a named outlet which is inside my main router outlet.
I have one component : `calculateur.component.ts`, in which there is a `button` with this `router link` :

```
[routerLink]="['/',{ outlets: { resultats: 'synthese' } }]"
```

here is the routing configuration :

```
{

path: "indicateur",

    component: IndicateurComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "absenteisme",
        pathMatch: "prefix"
      },
        path: "calculateur",
        component: CalculateurComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: "synthese",
            component: SyntheseComponent,
            outlet: "resultats"
          },
          {
            path: "cout-direct",
            component: CoutDirectComponent,
            outlet: "resultats"
          },
          {
            path: "cout-indirect",
            component: CoutIndirectComponent,
            outlet: "resultats"
          }
        ]
      },
```

when i click on it, the url becomes : `http://localhost:4200/#/indicateur/calculateur(resultats:synthese)`, but nothing happens in the screen.

I am not sure about the issue causing the above behavior.

Comment: Think your routing is wrong, looks like it's expecting your named router outlet on `IndicateurComponent`, could you try adding the named router outlet on that component instead of where you are putting it.

Comment: You mean that i have to place the named router outlet on the parent component ? Because i really nead to use it on the calculator component. Can you help me highlighting what is bad on my router config ?

Answer (score 0):

The `routerLink` should be on your `IndicateurComponent`'s template (you probably named it as `indicateur.component.html`) and not on `CalculateurComponent`.

Also, make sure to add your `router-outlet` on your `IndicateurComponent`.